# handling forms in PHP MVC architecture

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to learn MVC architecture in PHP.
this is what I've got so far: (there are more views such as login,...)

[image]

this is my Database.php :

```
class Database {

    public static $host="127.0.0.1";
    public static $dbName= "db6";
    public static $username = "username";
    public static $password = "password";

    private static function connect() {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host.";dbname=".self::$dbName.";charset=utf8", self::$username, self::$password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($params);

            if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
            }

            
    }
```

}

and Controller.php:

```
class Controller extends Database {

public static function CreateView($viewName){
    require_once("./view/$viewName.php");
    static::doSomething();
}
```

}

and Route.php :

```
class Route {
public static $validRoutes = array();

public static function set($route, $function){
    self::$validRoutes[] = $route;
    //print_r(self::$validRoutes);
    if($_GET['url'] == $route) {
        $function->__invoke();
    }

}
```

}

in view/login.php I have a form for user login:

```
<form _lpchecked="1" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
         User Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="loguser" placeholder="User Name" name="loguser">
      </div>                       
      <div class="form-group">
        Password:<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="logpass">
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <a href="jhl.php">Cancel</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </div>
   </form>
```

How can I handle the form?
and also how can I complete my db class since it's only working for SELECT queries?
thanks inadvance

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for SO.  Can you perhaps edit it, to be a specific problem?  You could show your current approach that is failing.

Comment: I can see a few odd issues here, like your Controller being a 'Database'.  Your  Database creates a new connection for each query, you might want to recycle that connection.  You have peppered most of your classes with the keyword static.  Which is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: First of all, get rid of ALL the _**"static"**_ keywords. You don't need any static classes/methods - despite of how many frameworks work. Instead, learn about _**"dependency injection"**_. After that, learn to use a _**"dependency injection container"**_, like [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/). After that, get rid of _"Database"_ class completely. Despite of how many frameworks work: you don't need it at all!

Comment: Instead, create a PDO connection in the DI container and inject it - always the same instance (!) - in your controllers, where it's needed. After that, learn about moving most of the functionality out of controllers into other type of classes, called _**"application services"**_ (as part of a [service layer](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)). Then you'll pass the PDO connection to the application services, instead of controllers.

Comment: After that, learn about [data mappers](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [repositories](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Then you'll pass the PDO connection object to the data mappers, instead of passing it to the application services as before.

Comment: As for loading the classes: if not done already, you should use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) as _**autoloader for all class files**_.